# Initializing ViewController by passing a View Model

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to initialize a ViewController by passing a View Model as shown below:

import Foundation
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var vm: LoginViewModel
    
    init(vm: LoginViewModel) {
        self.vm = vm
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
}
```

The init?(coder: NSCoder) initializer is giving error since the vm property is not initialized. How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: Just call fatalError() instead of super.init(coder:). You only need that initializer for storyboard initialization.

Comment: Are you initialising your controller from a Storyboard or directly with code?

Comment: I may also use Storyboard initialization also.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Not exactly. There is a way to use a storyboard segue with a custom initializer.

Comment: The real question is: if you used a storyboard initialization, where would the ViewModel come from? What's your real view controller hierarchy here? Who creates the ViewModel for this view controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the problem by adding a `!` to your property. This basically makes it so that you can initialize without setting the property. The property will be nil if you don't assign a value to it.

`private var vm: LoginViewModel!`

Note that if you initialize via storyboard, you need to make sure you find a way to initialize the property via a segue.